# what is the cupy correct alternative for the numpy errstate attribute?

Tags: python, numpy, class, cupy

I'm looking for the correct cupy attribute equivalent to numpy's `errstate` attribute, but the maximum I got is in this doc https://readthedocs.org/projects/cupy/downloads/pdf/stable/

[image]